# Renaming files recursively with Python

Tags: python, recursion, renaming

I have a large directory structure, each directory containing multiple sub-directories, multiple .mbox files, or both.  I need to rename all the .mbox files to the respective file name without the extension e.g.
  bar.mbox -> bar
  foo.mbox -> foo

Here is the script I've written:

```
# !/usr/bin/python
import os, sys

def walktree(top, callback):
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(top):
        for filename in files:
            fullPath = os.path.join(path, filename)
            callback(fullPath)

def renameFile(file):
    if file.endswith('.mbox'):
        fileName, fileExt = os.path.splitext(file)
        print file, "->", fileName
        os.rename(file,fileName)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    walktree(sys.argv[1], renameFile)
```

When I run this using:

```
python walktrough.py "directory"
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./walkthrough.py", line 18, in <module>
    walktree(sys.argv[1], renameFile)
  File "./walkthrough.py", line 9, in walktree
    callback(fullPath)
  File "./walkthrough.py", line 15, in renameFile
    os.rename(file,fileName)
OSError: [Errno 21] Is a directory
```

Comment: It would help if you showed a list of the files in the directory. Maybe printing some debugging information while running the code will help - also, you can try `shutil.move()` instead of `os.rename()`

Comment: Look at this question and see if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17510476/oserror-errno-21-is-a-directory. Similar suggestion was given by @WKPlus below.

Comment: OK, my answer was delete, because I just pointed out the cause to the error not the solution. But for this problem, in my opinion, the reason is more than the solution. Sorry for the complain, get back to this question. The error you encountered was caused by that you were trying to rename a file to the name which was occupied by an existing directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by adding an extra conditional statement to test if the name the file was to be changed to, was a current directory.

If this was true, the filename to-be had an underscore added to.

Thanks to WKPlus for the hint on this.

BCvery1